# Need to find whether a number already exists in any of given ranges

Tags: c, data-structures

I have multiple ranges configured which can increase/decrease dynamically, I need to find the fastest way to find whether a given number exists is any of the ranges, if yes then return the range? Can someone please suggest me the fastest algorithm or data structure in C to do such an operation?

The Code snippet is as follows:

```
addr = GET_U32BIT(buf);

    /* Search for the corresponding address */
    while(i < addr_table_size)
    {
        if((addr >= ntohl(table->addr_id[i].start_addr)) && \
                (addr <= ntohl(table->addr_id[i].end_addr)))
        {
            addr_present = 1;
            range_id = i;
            break;          
        }
        i++;
    }
```

In the above code, addr is a 4 byte number that is derived from a buffer received at runtime, while doing a linear search in a table where start and end addr are stored, the performance is very low as table can have around 50,000 to 100,000 entries.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code at least, or prototype of your datastructure.

Comment: Is this the bottleneck in your program?  Have you profiled it?  Is a linear search too slow?

Comment: Please find the code snippet in the original post..thx

Comment: What search algorithms have you tried?  Did even bother to do a google search on the subject?

Comment: Do the given ranges in table->addr_id[] overlap? If not, are they sorted? Finally, are they evenly distributed, i.e. for any number in the total range [0 - 4Bi), are the odds the same that the value falls within one of the given ranges? (Hopefully, the answers are no, yes and yes.)

Comment: @JMcF The answers are no i.e the ranges don't overlap, as well as they are not sorted and its possible that the addr may not lie in any of the given ranges. The size of different ranges are also not the same. For example one range can have starting address 0x00001010 and ending address as 0x00001090 and other can have starting address as 0x00002050 to 0x00030000.

Comment: @RAVITANDON: In that case, you can sort the ranges and do a binary search.  It will be much faster than a linear search.

Comment: @Jake Yeah..I tried to do the google search but didn't found the best match, as someone suggests that I should use BST or an RB Tree, but its not mentioned that how should I build such algorithms so that I can utilize them for my search, as the ranges are not in sorted order during initialization (I think if I try to sort such entries at the initialization for around 50k to 100k entries, it will take too much time to load it at startup) and can be added or deleted at run time.

Comment: You are just plain going to have to do some reading.  Data structures and their sorting/search algorithms is a massive subject with a massive amount of information on it.
Pretty much ANYTHING is going to be better than a while loop running over an array, so start with the tried and true "binary chop" style search algorithm, test it, and go from there.  It is going to be impossible for anyone to tell you what is going to be best, you are going to have to do some testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Interval tree.
For each range insert one entry in interval tree.

Now if you want to search for range in which number 'k' lies.
Search in interval tree. 
Also whenever a range changes delete that range from Interval and and reinsert it with new values.